# Error in arguments of pvalcombination

Tags: r

When I run this code

```
wk = loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")  
df = readWorksheet(wk,sheet="Sheet1")  
df 
df<-t(df) #each row has a gene and each column has a person(healthy or ill)          
mdat1 <- matrix(df[1,1:52], nrow = 1,ncol = 52, byrow = TRUE)
#matrix with the 1st gene in row and and people that express this gene for the 1st study 

mdat2 <-matrix(df[1,53:151], nrow = 1, ncol = 99, byrow = TRUE)
#matrix with the 1st gene in row and and people that express this gene for the 2nd study

mdat3 <- matrix(df[1,152:168], nrow = 1, ncol = 17,byrow = TRUE)
#matrix with the 1st gene in row and and people that express this gene for the 3rd study

mdat4 <- matrix(df[1,169:182], nrow = 1, ncol = 14,byrow = TRUE)
#matrix with the 1st gene in row and and people that express this gene for the 4th study

listgene1 <- list(mdat1,mdat2,mdat3,mdat4)  
listgene1  
#the 22th row  has 0 or 1 , 2 states 0 is ill and 1 is healthy 

f1 <-factor(df[22,1:52]) 
#factor with the 2 states for the 1:52 people from 1st study 

f2 <-factor(df[22,53:151])
#factor with the 2 states for the 53:151 people from 2nd study

f3 <-factor(df[22,152:168])
#factor with the 2 states for the 152:168 people from 3rd study 

f4 <-factor(df[22,169:182])
#factor with the 2 states for the 169:182 people from 4th study 

caselist <- list(f1,f2,f3,f4) 
pvalcombination(esets=listgene1,classes=caselist, moderated = c("t"),BHth = 0.05)
```

The outcome is

> Error in rowMeans(mat1, na.rm = TRUE) : 
>   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

any suggestions?

Comment: usually that means you are trying to take the `rowMeans(1:5)` of a vector. please make your question reproducible

Comment: But I'm not trying to take rowMean in my code. I think that it doesn't agree with the dimensions of the matrices that are used in lists of pvalcombination

Comment: If `listgene1` is, indeed, a valid input for `pvalcombination`, then you could call `debug(pvalcombination)` before calling `pvalcombination` and track where or in which sub-function the error occurs and why the format reached at that stage is not appropriate.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you very much i'll try it and i'll let you know if it works